# use one image loader gif within a comment voting system

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a coments stystem that allows users to upvote and downvote.

e.g something like this alongside each comment.

```
<div class="voteup_*commentid*">UpVote</div>
<div class="votecount_*commentid*">25</div>
<div class="votedown_*commentid*">DownVote</div>
```

When the user clicks one of the vote divs i want an ajax loader spinner to replace the points whilst it's fetching the updated score.

whats the best way i can do this?

ideally with just one spinner on the page that is positioned in the relvant "votecount" class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the button is clicked, add a loading spinner, and when it is finished, remove the loading spinner.

```
$(.voteup, .votedown).click(function(){
  $(this).append("<img src='spinner.gif' id='spinner' />");
  $.ajax({
    //ajax function here
  success: function(){
    $("#spinner").remove();
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: im using $.post() can i still do something like this?

Comment: Yes. Just put the code that removes the spinner inside the post function.